# How to hide the activities of sites that's showing up in the SharePoint Following page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

This is my end user's question below.

He said that in his SharePoint Following page.

From yesterday, user activities have begun shown under the site name.

He wants to hide the activities like earlier when only site title was displayed in the cards ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The page you are referring to is `https://[tenant-name].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx`.

This page is not customizable. The rendering and content displayed on the page is controlled by Microsoft.

The only way to turn off activities is to disable Graph from SP admin center. But once you disable it, you lose all functionality in Office 365 that is powered by the Graph, like Delve.

[image]

Reference - [Office Delve for Office 365 admins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Delve-for-Office-365-admins-54f87a42-15a4-44b4-9df0-d36287d9531b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_effectofficegraphonoff)

Having said that, activities in these cards are always security trimmed. It only shows the documents which you have access to.